# pass kwargs for the view in reverse; django 1.5

Tags: python, django

Being a django starter, I have a little problem to deal with:

## html code:

```
<li><a href="{% url 'dyn_display' category='first'%}">first</a></li>
<li><a href="{% url 'dyn_display' category='second'%}">second</a></li>
<li><a href="{% url 'dyn_display' category='third'%}">third</a></li>
```

## urlconf.py

```
url(r'(?P<category>[a-z]+)$', 'display', name='dyn_display')
```

## view.py

```
def courses_display(request, category):
    return render_to_response('display/basic.html', {category: 'in'}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

and finally a part of basic.html, so you can get a thought of why i need that category variable

## basic.html

```
<div class="accordion" id="accordion2">
    <div class="accordion-group">
        <div class="accordion-heading">
            <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseFirst">
                <strong>First</strong>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseFirst" class="accordion-body collapse {{ first }}">
             <div class="accordion-inner">
                 ...
             </div>
         </div>
     </div>
     <div class="accordion-group">
         <div class="accordion-heading">
             <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseSecond">
                 <strong>Second</strong>
             </a>
         </div>
         <div id="collapseSecond" class="accordion-body collapse {{ second }}">
             <div class="accordion-inner">
                 ...
             </div>
         </div>
     </div>
     <div class="accordion-group">
         <div class="accordion-heading">
             <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseThird">
                 <strong>Third</strong>
             </a>
         </div>
         <div id="collapseThird" class="accordion-body collapse {{ third }}">
             <div class="accordion-inner">
                 ...
             </div>
         </div>
      </div>
  </div>
```

Since the whole page is done with bootstrap and Jquery, last parts of url

some/url/**first**

some/url/**second**

some/url/**third**

are kind of ugly, since the accordion element lets me collapse and open respective inner bodies without reloading the page. So the question is: is there a way to pass a kwarg in reverse, that's going to be used in a view, not to determine the url in reverse()?

the way I get url like **some/url/** and, still passing kwarg from the first .html page to the view?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use this:

If this was your url:

```
url(r'(?P<category>[a-z]+)$', 'display', name='dyn_display')
reverse('dyn_display', kwargs={'category': 'first'})
```

To redirect you can use it like this in your view:

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('dyn_display', kwargs={'category': 'first'}))
```

If this was your url:

```
url(r'$', 'display', name='dyn_dysplay')
reverse('dyn_display')
```

To redirect you can use it like this in your view:

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('dyn_display'))
```

To have a view that could receive an optional value you would need 2 urls:

```
url(r'$', 'display', name='dyn_optional_display')    
url(r'(?P<category>[a-z]+)$', 'display', name='dyn_display')
```

And then your view:

```
def courses_display(request, category=None):
    ctx = {}
    if category:
        ctx.update({category: 'in'})
    return render_to_response('display/basic.html', ctx,    context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: isn't reverse function is a python-code analog of what I have in template, using url tag? Your approach, if I understand correctly, will look for a url match, in which there is a 'category' group to be captured, so it won't work on simple url(r'$', 'display', name='dyn_dysplay'). Also, where should I put the python code, since I'm going to some page with specific option right from template? The only other option I can see is a redirect, but that should involve reverse as well, which I still think I can't use to pass kwargs to the **view**, not to find match in urlpatterns.

Comment: Yeah, I see that. Thank you for so quick responses. But, forgive me, I still have some troubles figuring out this for me. All your ways do work fine, but in first two cases I'll still get the **ugly** url **some/url/first**, but I WILL pass the needed variable to the view in order to open the appropriate container. Rest of approaches do give me a nice url **some/url/**, but I can't pass the required argument to the view, I'm calling from urlpatterns, in order to expand the respective container.

Comment: So your problem is that you don't know how to get the values out of the url? sorry if I don't completely understand.

Comment: What are you trying to do with this part: {category: 'in'}?? This would set a context value equal to the category, which means that you would have a dictionary that actually looks like this: {'first': 'in'} by the time it gets to the template, if you want to pass the category you should use something like this: {'category': category}

Comment: No, the problem is, that i don't know how to resolve the **nice** url without arguments being present in it, though still passing some arguments to the view function anyways? Something like this: go to url pattern, that doesn't contain parameters in it, get the view it matches and pass some arguments to it. I think this can be done only python-code way, not the template.

Comment: So I want to pass category variable to the view and use it in function the way it used, but I don't want it to be present in the url pattern.

Comment: What values do you then want to pass to the template if there are no values in the url

Comment: Values, that indicate what block of accordion element I should expand. Like, if a click the **First** link in the html code I've provided, I want to go to **some/url/**, but I also want to specify to the view function, that I want to expand exactly first block inside the accordion element.

Comment: In the updated part: you're saying there's no way to get the first url match, but still pass some arguments to the view function at the same time? So we keep the url clean, but pass arguments at the same time? Like **some/url/** with category value passed inside view function?

Comment: if is the first url this: some/url/first

Comment: Still not what I want. I want the url to be **some/url/** but still be able to pass category value into the view function. So user goes to **some/url/** by clicking the link, and, depending on the link he clicked, he gets to the **some/url/** with respective container being expanded.

Comment: so basically the category should be passed to the view but you dont want to display it in the url

Comment: exactly! any way to accomplish that?

Comment: If you post the category to the url then in the view just get it from the request like request.POST.get('category', False) it would not show up in the url

Comment: can your explane that in a little bit more details?

Comment: if you use a form and set the method as post: <form action="{% url dyn_display %}" method="post"></form> you could add a hidden field in there which holds the value of the category and make a link that submits the form to that url, once it is submitted you could get the category from the post data in the view like request.POST.get('category', False)